# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTransformer') in Jest with ReactNative

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I found this problem trying to run a test using Jest in a React Native project:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTransformer')`

My `packages.json` related versions:

```
...
"jest": "27.4.5",
...
"ts-jest": "27.1.2",
...
```

I think that is related with packages versions, but I don't find the way to solve it.